# Smooth CSS gradients

Tags: css, css-gradients

I'm learning how to use CSS gradients.

My problem is with top to bottom gradients. You can just *see* the "stops" in the color changing.

[image]

This is my CSS code

```
#header { 
   width:1000px; 
   height:250px; 
   background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #BF7A30 30%, #EDD599); 
   background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BF7A30 30%, #EDD599); 
}
```

Is there a way to smooth out the stops in top to bottom gradients? (this, to my eye, isn't very visible in left to right or right to left gradients)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Think's below css will suite your need.

**CSS :**

```
#header {
    width:1000px;
    height:250px;
    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #EDD799 0%, #BF7F37 100%);
    /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #EDD799 0%, #BF7F37 100%);
    /* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #EDD799 0%, #BF7F37 100%);
    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #EDD799), color-stop(1, #BF7F37));
    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #EDD799 0%, #BF7F37 100%);
    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #EDD799 0%, #BF7F37 100%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xPLPH/

**Learn more about Linear Gradients:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: This is not a solution to the named problem with visible color-stops. You are just suggesting not to use color-stops between gradient and move them to edges: first to 0%, last to 100%. You can see this if you move color-stops just like in question's author code: http://jsfiddle.net/zoaporx0/1/

Comment: Not an answer at all. The edge is still visible.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem

Answer (score 15):

The main cause of this bending effect is actually the linear blending of colors, which is not as harmonious to the human eye.

Andreas Larsen has written a pretty elaborate article on css-tricks.com (2017).
https://css-tricks.com/easing-linear-gradients/

It describes a concept of non-linear gradients by defining multiple color stops approximating a clothoid curve.

Would result in something like this (.gradient-clothoid):

```css
.gradient-wrp {
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  flex: 0 0 none;
}

.gradient-linear {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#bf7a30 30%, #edd599);
}

.gradient-smooth {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#bf7a30 25%, 75%, #edd599);
}

.gradient-clothoid {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    rgba(191, 122, 48, 1) 0%,
    rgba(191, 122, 48, 0.3) 50%,
    rgba(191, 122, 48, 0.15) 65%,
    rgba(191, 122, 48, 0.075) 75.5%,
    rgba(191, 122, 48, 0.037) 82.85%,
    rgba(191, 122, 48, 0.019) 88%,
    rgba(191, 122, 48, 0) 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-wrp">
  <div class="header gradient-linear"></div>
  <div class="header gradient-smooth"></div>
  <div class="header gradient-clothoid"></div>
</div>
```

This concept is also known as "scrim".

IMHO not so well suited for "starting" color stops like the original example:

- the top 30% of gradient should have 100% color intensity. Probably to ensure better text readability for a heading
- the remaining 70% should have a smooth color transition.

I actually prefer Amelia Bellamy-Royds’ proposal (article down below in the comments) using a (well supported) gradient smoothing by adding stop without color definition like so:

```
.gradient-smooth{
   background-image:linear-gradient(#BF7A30 25%, 75%, #EDD599); 
}
```

This will smooth the gradient between 25% and 75% to the bottom spline based and not linear.

```
.gradient-linear{
   background-image:linear-gradient(#BF7A30 30%, #EDD599); 
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

As @nighthawk2534 mentioned, adding more colors to the gradient is the way to go. Obviously, those have to be "right" colors.

I don't know color theory enough, but stumbled upon a great tool for that:
https://mycolor.space/gradient

For your example it gives:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #bf7a30, #ca9148, #d5a861, #e1bf7d, #edd599);
```

Which looks like that:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcZ2t.png)

(I know this thread is very old, but still may be helpful)

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
background-color: #bf7a30;
background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #bf7a30 0%, #edd599 46%, #bf7a30 100%);
```

I generated it real easy from [www.gradientcss.com](http://www.gradientcss.com)

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.