# How to make CSS gradient look smooth?

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients, smoothing

I have a black background and want to add a block inside with simple CSS gradient from transparent to 0.7 white:

```
linear-gradient(to right, 
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0), 
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.76) 14%, 
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.76)
)
```

But this looks bad:

[image]

The only way I found is to add additional color stops, manually.

```
background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0),
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.05) 2%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.09) 3%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.2) 5%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.57) 11.5%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.69) 14%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75) 16.5%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.76) 17.5%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.77)
);
```

And it looks much better:

[image: The comparsion demonstration]

[The comparsion demonstration on CodePen](http://codepen.io/Grawl/pen/JbQwxj)

Is there an easier way to make CSS gradient smooth on color stops?

Comment: You can check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151331/smooth-css-gradients

Comment: I have already read it before creating my own question. There is no solutions in that question. Chosen answer is just suggestion to not use color-stops except 0 and 100%. I want to solve this problem, not a workaround.

Comment: I'm afraid not, but you could use the basic settings from these examples http://codepen.io/taylorvowell/pen/BkxbC

Comment: @Roberrrt there is no linear gradients with color-stops in between, except «Faded» (5) – 0 and 80%^ but colors is too identical to see color stop.

Comment: Ahhhh I see, it has to be linear?

Comment: Yes, it's obvious it should be linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One day, I hope, we've got this:

```
linear-gradient(
  to top,
  hsla(330, 100%, 45%, 0),
  cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.5, 0.5),
  hsla(330, 100%, 45%, 1)
);
```

Bot for now, we have this:

- PostCSS plugin with 2 options: https://github.com/larsenwork/postcss-easing-gradients
- An app allowng you to choose an easing function: https://larsenwork.com/easing-gradients/

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fully understand yet what it is what you intend to do, but as far as I got it would you like to add a box on a black background with a gradient on the left side from transparent (so still black) to white with 0.7 transparency or #C2C2C2. If that's what you'd like to do, I'd not use hsl (because of basic color theory) but rather rgba.

Check this out:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#blackbg {
background-color: black;
height: 300px;
}

#grad1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)); 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

If this wasn't what you intended to do or you still feel stuck with something, feel free to ask me back.

```
<div id="blackbg">
<div id="grad1"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to add this as a text background on my slider with an image background. It can be dark or light, anything like wallpapers from people desktops. You can see it at http://eco-vpk.ru or on this screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/73Ozc

Comment: okay, now I get it. But where do you want to add the gradient to? Where the product is? Do you work for VKP or is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am working on this website and a gradient I want to be smooth is under a product image.

Comment: Could you do it or do you still need any help? :)

Comment: Gradient on that website is the same that gradient in my question. It's manually-tuned to look smooth. I want to automate it.