# Tailwind linear-gradient, how to soften edge line between colors

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have following gradient on after element

```
after:bg-gradient-to-b after:from-gray-900 after:via-transparent after:via-20%
```

so I just want the gradient to be near the top of screen. Issue is that you can clearly see the line between transparent and color, how can I smoothen that line out so there would be smooth transition between the two?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smooth CSS gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151331/smooth-css-gradients)